# var data = Database.Open("databasename").Query("SELECT * FROM table); visual studio

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, foreach, webmatrix

I know you can do this in web matrix and it works fine

```
var data = Database.Open("databasename").Query("SELECT * FROM table); visual studio
```

but how can you achieve something similar in visual studio 2010 using MVC3???

I need to be able to loop through table rows using a `foreach()` and implement them through an api, I originally started the project in web matrix, but was asked to use mvc in visual studios instead, i have limited knowledge with it. I am using Microsoft sql server.

Also if anyone thinks I might be going the complete wrong way about achieving this, any input to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Easiest way, look into EntityFramework. To do just pure SQL check out ADO.net. Finding any tutorial on MVC will more than likely show you how to use EntityFramework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the ORM which most closely resembles WebMatrix is Dapper.

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

It can be used with dynamic objects in a very similar manner to WebMatrix, but can also be used with strongly typed objects if you wish. It's available as a NuGet package.

The code in your question would end up looking something like the following in Dapper:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databasename"].ConnectionString))
{
    var data = con.Query("SELECT * FROM table");

    foreach (var row in data)
        // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I have installed the ORM, and wrote my code as you have shown but i still get an error on "Query", 
Error 1 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this in a `.cshtml` file? If so, you'll need to add `@using Dapper;` to the top of it.